# Want to develop Java logic which dynamically checks child web elements present in parent web element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I expect a logic which dynamically checks how many children web elements does a parent webelement have.

eg.

- **Parent1**
- **Child1**
- *(Child1A, Child1B, Child1C)*
- (Child1A_A, Child1A_B, Child1A_C)
- (Child1B_A, Child1B_B)
- **Child2**
- *(Child2A, Child2B, Child2C)*

**Note:**

1. **Parent1** is the parent of **Child1** and **Child2**.
2. **Child1** is parent of *Child1A, Child1B, Child1C*
3. *Child1A* is the parent of Child1A_A, Child1A_B, Child1A_C
4. *Child1B* is the parent of Child1B_A, Child1B_B

   so on...

Expected: Want to develop a java logic which can check if the child exist, click on the child web element else move on to the next element.

It should check dynamically the presence of child and then click on the child Web element.

Comment: can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use a for loop                     int x = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[2]//a)")).size();
  System.out.println("Total number of Utility spend readings are - " + x);
  
  for (int k=1; k<=x; k++){}    Which just gave the count of total number of childs but didnt stop at the parent class. It was just counting the total number of web element